# Is there a faster way to look for the contents of one file in another?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I have two files

File f1 (has around 10000 unique lines only in one column)

```
Column1  
line1  
line2  
line3  
....  
line 10000
```

File f2 (has multiple columns and around 300000 lines)
The first column of file f2 has common elements with file f1. I want to grep those common elements (all 10000) along with the contents of other columns in file2.

[image]

So far, I have tried

```
grep -f f1 f2  
and also 
grep -F -f f1 f2
```

but both of these are giving me some extra lines in the final output (10000+). The first column of both the files have some contents separated by '/' which might need more text manipulations
eg. 
**Column1**
a/b/c
e/f/g
x/y

Comment: `grep -F -w -f f1 f2` or `grep -F -e '^\w\w*' -f f1 f2`? What extra content (`a/b/c`) doesn't match what you show for `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: Add example of File f2 with field separator to your question (no comment).

Comment: Do you want to extract from f2 only those lines having in column 1 the value which is present in f1?

Comment: I'm expecting an output like (extract only the common elements in column 1, along with the contents of column 2&3 in file2)
line1 x y
line 2 e f

Comment: It's contradictory: `File f1 (has around 10000 unique lines only in one column)` and `The first column of both the files have some contents separated by '/'`

Comment: I have some hierarchical contents in column 1 in both the files. Some elements in first column would be separated by '/'. Eg line1=a/b/c & line2=xyz.Other columns in file 2 are all numerical.

Comment: In that case `grep -F -e '^line' -f f1 f2` should work. (otherwise, `awk` is always available) Post text examples of the *Good* lines from each file and the *hierarchical contents* from each (~5 lines of each should do)

Comment: I agree with @DavidC.Rankin sir here, please post clear samples for input and expected output in form of text in your question and  let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -f` is a good start, however, there are two problems:

1. Depending on the data it could be troublesome to ensure, that exactly column 1 from file 2 is matched (not only parts of it and no other columns). **Examples:**

   - For the files `f1` = `line1` and `f2` = `line100 a b` you get a false positive since grep finds the string `line1` in `line100`. This could be prevented with grep's `-w` option.
   - For the files `f1` = `line1` and `f2` = `line2 a line1` you get a false positive since grep finds the string `line1` in the third column which shouldn't be searched at all. Errors like these are hard to prevent using `grep`. A safe way would be to generate extended regex patterns (something like `grep -Ef <(sed 's/.*/^& /' f1) f2`, requires additional effort to quote the lines from `f1`) but that would be complicated and slow.
2. The command could be more efficient. Depending on the implementation `grep -f` may check all `n` lines from file 1 for every of the `m` lines in file 2. 
   In the worst case there would be `O(n*m)` line operations.

The following command may run faster. Also, there won't be false positives. This is a simple version for files without headers:

```
join <(sort f1) (sort f2)
```

and this is the version for files with headers

```
hsort() { IFS= read -r header; printf %s\\n "$header"; sort; }
join --header <(hsort < f1) <(hsort < f2)
```

I expect this to do at most `O(m log m)` line operations.

<sub>O(sorting f1 + sorting f2 + joining)

= O(n log n + m log m + max(n,m)) | n < m

= O(2 m log m + m)

= O(m log m)</sub>